# javascript prompt box for reCAPTCHA

Tags: php, javascript, prompt

I'm trying to make an automatic prompt box which displays the error of an incorrect reCAPTCHA input, at the moment I have a function 'redirect_to' which links to an identical page, which i planned to just input a error in text form. If anyone could help me with this I'd be much appreciated, i'm not had too much experience with javascript.

```
 require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/recaptcha/recaptchalib.php');
        $privatekey ="*********";
        $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                            $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
                            $_POST['recaptcha_challenge_field'],
                            $_POST['recaptcha_response_field']);
        $str_result = "";
        if (!$resp->is_valid) {

            redirect_to("login_recap.php");

             // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
            $message = "The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again. (reCAPTCHA   said: " . $resp->error . ")";
            echo $message;
            exit();

        }
```

Comment: HOw is this different from the other question you asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483470/using-a-javascript-prompt-box-when-recaptcha-wasnt-enter-correctly?

Comment: Stop asking the same question(s) multiple times.  You can edit the original question, instead of asking a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect back to the login page with a GET parameter such as: `login.php?captchaError=1`. Then on your login page, simply add:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['captchaError]))
{
echo("<script type='text/javascript'>
alert("Captcha entered incorrectly.");
</script>
");
}
?>
```

That will check if there is an error and output some JS to display the alert.